# How hist() handles zeroes

Tags: r, histogram

first-time poster, relative R newbie (I've taken a few Coursera classes over the past two years). I've found some behavior with the hist() function I don't really understand; apologies if this has already been answered, but I couldn't find anything.

I read an article saying there were 1,280 police killings in the U.S. last year and only 14 days when they didn't happen. I thought 14 sounded low, so I decided to see what random numbers would look like. (Should have just done ppois, but bear with me.) I don't have enough reputation to do images, but if you run this code it sure looks like like 40-some zeros.

```
set.seed(0)
hist(rpois(365, lambda = 1280/365))
```

But when I run

```
sum(rpois(365, lambda = 1280/365) == 0)
```

I always get somewhere around 10, which is the correct answer (and in line with the article). And if I plot it in ggplot instead, I get an extra bar that goes up to around 10, properly placed between 0 and 1, with the other bars shifted to the right:

```
set.seed(0)
randomnos <- as.data.frame(rpois(365, lambda = 1280/365))
colnames(randomnos) <- "Numbers"
ggplot(randomnos, aes(Numbers)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

Apparently the hist() function (A) isn't plotting the zeroes and (B) is putting the 1's between 0 and 1 on the X axis. ggplot behaves differently. What gives?

Comment: Have a look at the `right` argument of `hist`. `set.seed(0); x <- rpois(365, lambda = 1280/365) ; h <- hist(x, right=FALSE); table(x) ;h$counts`

Comment: Also i think ggplot does the equivalent of `barplot(table(x))`

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. Still seems like weird default behavior for it not to plot all the data I gave it, but no one ever called R intuitive.